# SoapUI Script Assertion to validate the keys are present without validating the values within the keys

Tags: json, groovy, soapui, assertions

I have a REST request that will return a json response with a set of nine keys and there values. No the input values for the request are randomized and therefore will I will get different values every time it is run.

Is is possible to create a script assertion that will just validated whether the json structure is correct.

Json Response:

```
{
   "sid": 636811,
   "poss": 122,
   "mis": -150,
   "pres": 253,
   "aea": 0,
   "aa": 12,
   "ua": 7,
   "lar": null,
   "lbr": 1
}
```

Script Assertion:

```
def expectedMap = [sid:'', poss:'', mis:'', pres:'', aea:'', aa:'', ua:'', lar:'', lbr:'']
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response))

assert json.keySet().sort() == expectedMap.keySet().sort()
```

I believe the following script assertion I have is failing because is it asserting the key values as well.

```
log.info expectedMap.keySet().sort()
log.info json.keySet().sort()

Tue Jun 26 14:27:52 BST 2018:INFO:[aa, aea, lar, lbr, mis, poss, pres, sid, ua]
Tue Jun 26 14:27:52 BST 2018:INFO:[aa, aea, lar, lbr, mis, poss, pres, sid, ua]

log.info expectedMap.keySet().sort().getClass()
log.info json.keySet().sort().getClass()

Tue Jun 26 14:17:12 BST 2018:INFO:class java.util.ArrayList
Tue Jun 26 14:17:12 BST 2018:INFO:class java.util.TreeMap$KeySet
```

Comment: Ross, please check the solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Just need to get the keys, sort them and compare.

Change from:

```
assert expectedMap == json, 'Actual response is not matching with expected data'
```

To:

```
assert expectedMap.keySet().sort() == json.keySet().sort() as List, 'Actual response is not matching with expected data'
```

Comment: Script is failing, however when I `log.info expectedMap.keySet().sort()` and `log.info json.keySet().sort()`, they are exactly the same.

Comment: Quick question: what gives each of `expectedMap.keySet().sort().getClass()` and `json.keySet().sort().getClass()` ?

Comment: `class java.util.ArrayList` and `class java.util.TreeMap$KeySet`

Comment: If that is the case, then you need to show the data.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: The sample provided works for the Data presented in the question. When you say there is error, actual data may differ. So asked for the data used in actual case. Need not be exact, but at least same structure.

Comment: Updated the question. I hope that helps.

Comment: Updated answer, please retry.

Comment: Thank you very much